# Maintaining WPF MVVM View Model & Model Relationships

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

this seems like a basic question but I can't figure out the best implementation.  How do you manage the relationships between two view models and their corresponding models.

For instance, if you changed the Occupation property on PersonViewModel, how does that change trickle down to the Occupation property in the PersonModel.

The only way I can see it right now is publicly exposing the model in the view model, but I thought that defeated the purpose of MVVM - decoupling the model from the view.

```
internal class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly PersonModel person;

    private OccupationViewModel occupation;

    public PersonViewModel(PersonModel person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public OccupationViewModel Occupation
    {
        get { return this.occupation; }
        set 
        { 
            if (!this.occupation.Equals(value))
            {
                this.occupation = value;
                this.person.Occupation = this.occupation.Occupation; // Doesn't seem right

                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Occupation"));
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class OccupationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public OccupationViewModel(OccupationModel occupation)
    {
        this.Occupation = occupation;
    }

    public OccupationModel Occupation { get; set; } // Is this right?
} 

internal class PersonModel
{
    public OccupationModel Occupation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is PersonViewModel.Occupation a writable property? Typically it would be read-only -- after all, who's going to set it?

Comment: I was thinking of exposing it so that some other view model could change it.  Or is this where some method or command come in?  BTW, I'm a WPF, MVVM newbie.

Comment: Patrick I think what Joe is saying is that the view-model can be modified externally without setting it (by accessing its properties): `personViewModel.Occupation.Occupation = new OccupationModel("software engineer");`

Comment: …also, users won't get notified of your comments unless (a) you are commenting on their answers, (b) they have starred/favourited the question, or (c) you lead off the question with at least part of their name preceded by "@" -- like "@Joe I was thinking…"

Comment: @Jay, aren't there some cases where you would want to set the view-model directly?  I'm thinking of cases were the view model has lots of properties.  In my mind, it would be easier to set the property ("PersonViewModel.Occupation") than iterate through all the properties and change them.  What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your view-model *is* decoupling the model from the view. It seems like you may be confusing the concepts of the view and the view-model.

The view-model is both the gateway and the gatekeeper between the two -- it determines what makes it from the model to the view and from the view back to the model, and in what form.

You can set the model property in the VM setter, or not. You could save up state from the view, and only propagate those changes to the model when the user clicks "save." You could persist that state elsewhere so someone can come back and work on it more before persisting it to the view.

The view-model can know the model intimately, so the view doesn't have to know it at all.

I'm not sure I follow your concern about publicly exposing the model in the view-model. You haven't done that in your sample code. You've exposed an object that is the same *type* as you use in the model, but this is like using `int` for age in both the model and view-model -- you haven't exposed the actual model object; you still have control over whether and when the value in the view-model gets set on the model.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  I was concerned about exposing OccupationModel in OccupationViewModel.  Is publicly exposing the model in the view model bad practice?  I'm under the assumption that the model should be encapsulated by the view model and hidden from everybody else.

Comment: @Patrick In simple, straightforward applications, it is sometimes expedient to expose the model directly. If you are dealing with a measure of complexity then yes, it is best to relay anything you want to expose through properties on the view-model. This is true more generally as an object-oriented principle, whenever you are dealing with composition.

Answer (score 5):

To show possible relationships between Model and ViewModel I first simplified your example by changing the type of `Occupation` into `string`. Then `PersonModel` and `PersonViewModel` might look like this:

```
public class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string occupation;
  public string Occupation
  {
    get
    {
      return this.occupation;
    }
    set
    {
      if (this.occupation != value)
      {
        this.occupation = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Occupation");
      }
    }
  }
}

public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private PersonModel model;

  public string Occupation
  {
    get
    {
      return this.model.Occupation;
    }
    set
    {
      this.model.Occupation = value;
    }
  }

  public PersonViewModel(PersonModel model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    this.model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(model_PropertyChanged);
  }

  private void model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
  }
}
```

The important difference to your version is that `PersonModel` and `PersonViewModel` *both* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This is important because otherwise changing a property of `PersonModel` directly (ie without going through `PersonViewModel`) will have no effect in the View. Also notice how the `PropertyChangedEvent` from the Model is piped up to the View.

Now suppose `Occupation` is not a `string` but a class with properties of its own, eg:

```
public class OccupationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private double salary;
  public double Salary
  {
    get
    {
      return this.salary;
    }
    set
    {
      if (this.salary != value)
      {
        this.salary = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using a ViewModel between your View and Model gives you some flexibility on how you present your data to the View. Here are two options how you could do it:

**Option 1** Expose the properties of `Occupation` directly in the `PersonViewModel`. This is a simple solution because you don't need to implement another ViewModel.

```
public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private PersonModel model;

  public double OccupationSalary
  {
    get
    {
      return this.model.Occupation.Salary;
    }
    set
    {
      this.model.Occupation.Salary = value;
    }
  }

  public PersonViewModel(PersonModel model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    this.model.Occupation.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(occupation_PropertyChanged);
  }

  private void occupation_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Occupation" + e.PropertyName);
  }
}
```

The `OccupationSalary` property gives direct access to the `Salary` property in `Occupation`. Notice how now the `PropertyChanged` event of `Occupation` needs to be handled, and that we have to rename the property in `occupation_PropertyChanged`.

**Option 2** (Recommended) Expose the properties of `Occupation` through an `OccupationViewModel`. You should do this if you need to implement any business logic specific to `Occupation`. Given your example, this is probably what you intended to do:

```
public class PersonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private PersonModel model;
  private OccupationViewModel occupationViewModel;
  public OccupationViewModel OccupationViewModel
  {
    get
    {
      return this.occupationViewModel;
    }
  }

  public PersonViewModel(PersonModel model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    this.occupationViewModel = new OccupationViewModel(this.model.occupation);
  }
}

public class OccupationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private OccupationModel model;

  public double Salary
  {
    get
    {
      return this.model.Salary;
    }
    set
    {
      this.model.Salary = value;
    }
  }

  public OccupationViewModel(OccupationModel model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    this.model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(model_PropertyChanged);
  }

  private void model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
  }
}
```

As you can see `OccupationViewModel` has exactly the same structure as the simplified `PersonViewModel` I showed in the beginning. The important difference to your version of `OccupationViewModel` is that it exposes the *properties* of `OccupationModel`, not `OccupationModel` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should just expose a 'Person' property on your PersonViewModel instead of exposing an Occupation property. The Occupation property seems like an uncecessary layer.

The person property would look something like below and the Occupation property could be referenced by something like this 'viewModel.Person.Occupation'.

```
        public Person Person
    {
        get
        {
            return this.person;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!this.person.Equals(value))
            {
                this.person = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Person"));
            }
        }
    }
```